# Convert closed Linestrings from OSMnx graph into Multipolygon

Tags: python, shapely, osmnx

I'm retrieving some geometries from OpenStreetMap with OSMnx library with the following code:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('Casco Viejo, Bilbao, Spain', network_type='walk', 
                        retain_all=True, buffer_dist = 50, which_result = 2,
                        infrastructure = 'relation["highway" = "pedestrian"]')
```

which yields the following graph composed by shapely linestrings:

[image]

Then I convert the graph into a geopandas geodataframe:

```
ped = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes = False)
```

I've tried this to convert `Linestrings` to `Points` and then `Points` to `Multipolygon`

Is there a way to convert this linestrings into a shapely `Multipolygon`:

```
from shapely import geometry, ops

# combine them into a multi-linestring
multi_line = geometry.MultiLineString(list(ped['geometry']))

merged_line = ops.linemerge(multi_line)

from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

points = []
for i in range(0, len(merged_line)):
    points.append((Point(list(merged_line[i].coords[1]))))

coords = [p.coords[:][0] for p in points]

poly = Polygon(coords)
```

This yields a weird wrong geometry:

```
shape(poly)
```

If I try:

```
MultiPolygon(points)
```

It gives this Error Message: `TypeError: 'Point' object is not subscriptable`

Is there a way to transform `Linestrings` into `Multipolygon` and this into `GeoDataFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to construct a graph using the `ox.graph_from_X` functions, it does not make sense to have polgons or multipolygons, as a graph model is merely a set of elements (nodes) linked to one another by edges.

If you just want the geometries (points, polygons, multipolygons, etc) of walkable elements in the area, then you should use the [pois](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.pois) module to get a GeoDataFrame of geometries (without any graph topology), like:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
place = 'Casco Viejo, Bilbao, Spain'
gdf = ox.pois_from_place(place, which_result=2, tags={'highway':'pedestrian'})
gdf.shape #(87, 56)
```

Finally, note that your usage of the `infrastructure` parameter was deprecated a few releases ago and removed in a previous release. You may want to update the package to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff, but the outcome isn't good enough for my purpose. 
When printing the result there are errors in the performance of many polygons.

`fig, ax = ox.plot_shape(gdf.loc[(gdf.geom_type == 'Polygon') | (gdf.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon')])`